# Python - how to a open remote file in binary read mode?

Tags: python, binary, io, metadata, mutagen

I'm trying to use the mutagen module to read the metadata of an `mp3` file. The problem is that the module is expecting a local `mp3` file, but my `mp3` files are on a remote server.

This is the line in the module that raises an error when I send a remote mp3 URL as the first parameter.

```
fp = file(f, "rb")
```

How can I alter this line of code so that it can open a remote file (e.g. `http://remotedomain.com/file.mp3`) in `rb mode`?

Comment: +1 to counteract downvote. the question was worded clearly and the OP made an effort. this is what SO is all about, guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fp = urllib2.urlopen("http://remotedomain.com/file.mp3")
```

binary mode is default

Comment: I +1'ed but dude please make less comments alright? You talk very redundant, that's what you get -1's.

Answer (score 4):

file() can not be used to fetch arbitrary URLs.

See

http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/urllib2.html